# Jest + Firebase: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defineProperties' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, jestjs

I'm currently working on an react native project and wanted to utilise the  Firebase JS SDK. To get familiar with all it's API's I thought of writing some learning tests with Jest. This is my test:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
describe('Firebase', function() {
  it('should work', function() {
    expect(null).toBeNull()
  })
});
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error:
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defineProperties' of undefined

  at node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:18:234
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:23:260)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js:8:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (firebase.test.js:1:104)
```

If I replace the import state with `import React from 'react'` everything works fine. So why can't I use Firebase to test some API calls.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.5.0",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.35.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "16.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "16.0.1",
    "jest-react-native": "16.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah same here. Firebase works great within the app itself, but once you try to run tests you get this error. Quite annoying :(

Comment: same here. did you figure out the solution to how to structure your app?

Comment: The same problem, if I do `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` I get `Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that installing and configuring the "jest-react-native" and "react-native" presets **breaks** our ability to "import" firebase! The fix is to `require` firebase (**not** `import`) in your test.js file, and add a line that imports `react-native`. Without `import`ing `react-native` in *addition* to `require('firebase')`, firebase will not be included in the test file! Here is my github [repo](https://github.com/benjaminboruff/jest-test) that walks you through the steps that reproduce the error, and how to fix it.

There may also be a stale jest cache which may require you to run

> ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --no-cach

This seems to happen everytime I change anything to do with a preprocessor option.

[See jest documentation on caching issues.](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/troubleshooting.html#caching-issues)

Comment: That's it for me! I think I was able to get it to work differently due to serendipitous jest caching :) I've tried this on my linux machine locally and on Cloud9. Both work. The main thing is to use the `"babel": { "presets": ["es2015", "react-native"]}`  OR I guess a .babelrc file with the same presets, INSTEAD of the jest prest.

Comment: Removing the Jest preset did indeed work, thanks! I will award the bounty as soon as I can (in 10 hours).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually solved my problem and I can `import Firebase` without any errors. Since that was my actual question I marked as answered :) Unfortunately removing `"jest": { "preset": "jest-react-native" }` breaks tests where I import "react-native" with the error: `ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined`. Any advice for that?

Comment: Wow! My thinking has been really uptight about this! I'll rewrite the answer after you test this and give me some feedback :) Here is the deal: there is no `"jest": {"preset": "es2015"}`, so to get firebase "imported" a la ES modules, you have to use the `"bable": {"presets": ["es2015"]}`, **BUT** that breaks something when using react/react-native via the `"jest"` option! So instead of `import Firebase` in your test.js file, just use `var Firebase = require('firebase')`, then add your `"jest": { "preset": "jest-react-native" }` back, and set `"babel": {"presets": ["react-native"]}`. Work?

Comment: Hello @BenjaminHBoruff I am having the similar problem. But even with `const firebase = require('firebase')` won't help. Here is my repo, would you please give some help? Thanks in advance. https://github.com/ivawzh/firebase-jest/tree/master

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time @BenjaminHBoruff! I made your suggested changes but I still get the aforementioned `__DEV__` error on the 'react-native' module. Importing Firebase still works just fine.

Comment: @ivan-wang, try removing the `"jest": {"testEnvironment": "node"}` from your `package.json` file. Does that help?

Comment: @Graf, I just got word from someone at FB who works on jest: "firebase is doing something funky, there is an open issue about it we haven't had time to fix it yet". So, it sounds like a firebase issue ...

Comment: Looks like removing `{"testEnvironment": "node"}` fixed my thing. I guess its a bug in Jest. Because I am really running NodeJs in server, I should not require JsDOM etc.

Comment: Yay @BenjaminHBoruff, I got it working with the help from your repo! Cheers Mate. And you're right, one thing is left: "WHY? That's the question that needs to be answered!". Another thing I've noticed: omitting the `import ReactNative from 'react-native';` after the `const Firebase = require("firebase");` leads again to the above mentioned TypeError. Weird... But anyways, thanks so much for your extensive help!

Comment: repo not found, attached in answer Link is broken

Comment: @PardeepJain Sorry, I deleted the repo when cleaning-out old repos. I just restored it. Thanks!